# Nativescript - setting background-image to none

Tags: css, sass, nativescript

Is there a way to set CSS background-image property to none or transparent.

I'm using SASS and themes, and in some themes I've got an image and for others I don't - so i'd like to set it to none.

`.my-class { background-image: $image; }`

Where $image is an SASS variable that could be set to a valid url or none/transparent.

btw, I did set it to 'none' and I get the following error

`Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: none`

I think NS is trying to download 'none' bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Setting property value to **null** seems to not include the property - which works.

This is under SASS.